# Why stack pointer %rsp is not (always) grown before using it?

Tags: c, linux, assembly, gcc, red-zone

I wrote a small example program to play around with:

```c
int f(int x){
  x = x + 1;
  return x;
}

int main(){
  int x = 10;
  x = f(x);
  return 0;
}
```

Compiled on x86-64:

```sh
gcc -o simple simple.c
```

And looked at disassembly for `f()`:

```
Dump of assembler code for function f:
   0x00000000004004cd <+0>:     push   %rbp
   0x00000000004004ce <+1>:     mov    %rsp,%rbp
=> 0x00000000004004d1 <+4>:     mov    %edi,-0x4(%rbp)
   0x00000000004004d4 <+7>:     addl   $0x1,-0x4(%rbp)
   0x00000000004004d8 <+11>:    mov    -0x4(%rbp),%eax
   0x00000000004004db <+14>:    pop    %rbp
   0x00000000004004dc <+15>:    retq
```

What throws me off a little bit is that it's writing to `%rbp-0x4`, with `%rbp` equal to `%rsp` at this point. What this means is we're writing 4 bytes beyond the top of the stack. I see why it's perfectly okay to do, since `f()` doesn't call anything, so stack will never grow unexpectedly here. But it still feels a bit strange. Is that some kind of optimization to save `sub 0x4, %rsp` and `add 0x4, %rsp` instructions?

Compiled with `gcc (GCC) 4.8.5`

Comment: This is called the *red zone.*  Let me find a suitable duplicate.

Comment: @fuz thanks for pointing in the right direction!